# undefined index: postevent....solved it but that created other problems

Tags: php, undefined-index

```
$citylink_view = "view=$targetview&postevent=$_GET[postevent]";
```

it was showing undefined index: postevent.
i  solved it  by using

```
$posteventview = $_GET['postevent'];
$citylink_view = "view=$targetview&".$posteventview;
```

but this is creating problems in my URL. functionality doesn't working....

Comment: Is `postevent` the name of a *GET* parameter or is it actually a variable in your *PHP* script? If we assume it's actually a variable we need to know what functionality doesn't work. How does your produced URL look and how do you expect it to work. `It doesn't work` is not enough information. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Bug_writing_guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situation before:

```
$citylink_view = "view=$targetview&postevent=$_GET[postevent]";
```

which is the same as:

```
$citylink_view = "view=$targetview&postevent=" . $_GET['postevent'];
```

Which can be written as:

```
$foo = $_GET['postevent'];
$citylink_view = "view=$targetview&postevent=" $foo;
```

You wrote:

```
$posteventview = $_GET['postevent'];
$citylink_view = "view=$targetview&".$posteventview;
```

Can you spot the difference?

Aside, you are possible vulnerable to XSS. Sanitize the input and `urlencode`. Use `filter_*` functions, e.g.:

```
$posteventview = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "postevent");
$citylink_view = "view=$targetview&postevent=" . urlencode($posteventview);
```